Why using llvm15.04 libtooling getAccess is public？
#ifndef C_H_
#define C_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class sptr {};

class IRemoteObject;

class Test{
public:
    Test(const std::string &bundleName, const std::string &abilityName, const int32_t &accountId){};

private:
    IRemoteObject Connect(){};
    sptr<IRemoteObject> DoConnect(){};
    
};


#endif


this mycode，i use llvm15.04 libtooling analyze this c++ code.
i get class Test Connect and DoConnect getAccessis return public，why?
how can i get right access?
this min demo i test

There must be something wrong with how you are querying the API.  Edit your question and add your complete libtooling program (it should compile, link, run, and print the access value you are seeing) so we can see what you are doing.
